# Interpreting "a close contact between A and B as well as C"

Tags: sentence-construction

Just saw a sentence like this. It's confusing.

When saying:

> There is close contact between A and B as well as C

does that means:

1. A is close to C, and B is close to C
2. A and B (as a whole) are close to C
3. A, B, and C are close to each other

For example

> There is close contact between the management and bank staff as well as their owners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with idiomatic phrases such as "as well as," it helps to have the sentence example that inspired the question.  Thank you for providing it.

In most business organizations, it is unusual for the owners and the general staff to have a close relationship.  Therefore, your sentence is describing the close relationships between management and staff, and management and the owners.  In context of your original question: A+B as well as A+C.

The original sentence could have been written better to clarify this, rather than relying on the context of the sentence alone.  For example:

> There is close contact between the management and bank staff as well as management and the bank's owners.
>
> There is close contact between both management and bank staff, and management and the bank's owners.
>
> The bank's management has close contact with both the bank's staff and it's owners.

Comment: If you find an answer useful, remember to upvote. When your question is answered you can accept the answer that you found most useful.